# Passing array into function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm trying to get the value input by the user from `scanf( "%d", &ar[rows][cols] );` into the the int variable `temp`.

But somehow when I execute, it gives me an error right after the `printf(  "Please enter 9 positive integers : " );`

Edit: I forgot to include the codes. Here are the codes:

```
/* File: StudentID_Surname.c  - e.g. 1234567_Wilson.c
 * This program finds the range between highest and lowest value of a 2-D array */

#include <stdio.h>

#define NROW 3
#define NCOL 3

/* Write a function
     void disp_arr(int a[NROW][NCOL]) { ... }
    where a[][] is the 2-D array
    Print the entire array to the screen. */

disp_arr( temp );

int main(void)
{
    /* declare needed variables or constants, e.g. */
    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int rows, cols, temp;

    /* prompt for the user to enter nine positive integers to be stored into the array */

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( cols = 0 ; cols < 3 ; cols++ )
            {
                printf(  "Please enter 9 positive integers : " );

                scanf( "%d", &ar[rows][cols] );

                temp = disp_arr(ar[rows][cols]);

                printf( "%d\t", temp );
            }
        printf("\n");
    }

}/* end main */

disp_arr( int temp )
{
    int x,y;
    int a[x][y];

    printf( "%d", a[x][y] );

    return a[x][y];
}
```

Where are my mistakes?

Comment: Please show a more complete example of your code. For example, how do you declare `ar`? What is `rows` and `cols`?Where does `temp` come into the picture?

Comment: Ah dammit I forgot to include the code. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I forgot to include the code. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Here's *one* big problem:

```
int x,y;
int a[x][y];
```

When you define local variables, they are not initialized by default. Instead their values are indeterminate, and using those values while uninitialized leads to undefined behavior.

You should also get lots of compiler warnings, and even errors (for e.g. the `disp_arr( temp );` function call in the global scope).

Also, even though undeclared functions are implied to return `int`, you should always specify it anyway.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the tips. I set the global scope to disp_arr( int temp ); as for the x,y, I am now adding loops to it~!

Answer (score 0):

If `ar` is a pointer, then you don't have to use `&` in `scanf`. You use `&` to tell `scanf` the *address* where you desire to store the value read from console. But, in case of pointer, the pointer already contains the address of data structure in which you want to store the read value. `ar[rows][cols]` itself translate to an address, so you don't have to put another `&` there.

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't mix up the user input with the printing. It says in that comment what the function should do and what its prototype should look like. So just do what it says. If you remove the user input from the code, then move the code you've already written to the function, you get:

```
void disp_arr (int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
  for (int rows=0; rows<NROW; rows++)
  {
    for (int cols=0; cols<NCOL; cols++)
    {
      printf("%d ", a[rows][cols]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```